How can I get the sp definition?
I want to obtain the definition of an SP by code, but, as is obtained when one presses the right clip on an SP and clicks modify.
I have tried this script
USE MY_DATA_B
GO
    DECLARE @TextoBuscar NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'FACTURAS';
SELECT
   o.name AS NombreObjeto,
   o.type_desc AS TipoObjeto,
   m.definition AS Definicion,
   SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id) AS Esquema
FROM
   sys.sql_modules AS m
INNER JOIN
   sys.objects AS o ON m.object_id = o.object_id
WHERE
   m.definition LIKE '%' + @TextoBuscar + '%'
ORDER BY
   o.type_desc, o.name;

but what I get in the Definicion column is not functional for me, since the SPs have comments with -- and from then on everything is shown to me as a comment.

In the previous image I show how I obtain it with the previous Script, the Yellow would be a comment and the Light Blue should be part of the functional code of the SP. Like the following image.


You should enable "keep spaces" when copypasting definition in SSMS

Duplicate of SSMS Results to Grid - CRLF not preserved in copy/paste - any better techniques? Though I could vote to reopen this, as it's now in English, I would then hammer it once it's open.

@ThomA strange, it seems one can't vote for closing after voting on reopening!

Please don't use images for data, code or errors. Use the appropriate text formatting (table markdown, code block or quoted text). I can't read anything in the images on my device.

You can, @siggemannen . You can't vote to close twice. You VTC'd due to the post not being in English initially.
